# Aumentar a "caixa de texto" do <Editor /> no Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, xaml, xamarin-forms

Salve pessoal! Vocês saberiam como posso fazer para aumentar o espaço de texto no Editor />" no Xamarin Forms? Da mesma forma que podemos aumentar um input /> no HTML com o padding ? Agradeço qualquer tentativa.

Gostaria que ficasse desse tamanho como na imagem... Porém no meu, ele fica bem menor, quase igual um Entry /> ... Gostaria de aumentar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `HeightRequest` no Editor. 
Um tamanho bacana para ele ficar é utilizar `HeightRequest="150"`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Me ajudou bastante, era exatamente o que eu procurava! :)